# resume video from the place where it stopped in Angular

Tags: angular

resume video from the place where it stopped in Angular. Below is the code snippet,

```
 @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      name = 'Angular 6';

  constructor() 
   {  }

    @ViewChild('iframe') iframe: ElementRef;

    ngOnInit() {

    }



    ngAfterViewInit() {
        alert('success');
        let doc = this.iframe.nativeElement.contentDocument || this.iframe.nativeElement.contentWindow;
        if (typeof doc.addEventListener !== undefined) {
          doc.addEventListener("click", this.iframeClickHandler, false)
        } else if (typeof doc.attachEvent !== undefined) {
          doc.attachEvent("onclick", this.iframeClickHandler);
        }
      }
      iframeClickHandler() {
        alert("Iframe clicked");
      }
}
```

## html

```
   <div>
        <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/197933516" frameborder="0" id="iframe" allowfullscreen
            #iframe></iframe>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things you need here:

- Get the current time of the video
- Save that current time somewhere
- Play the video from the saved timestamp (if there's one)

#### Here's a rough idea of a possible approach:

In your component, save the timestamp of the video in a `timestamp` variable

Here's how you can save the time: [Vimeo player time tracking using script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54398715/vimeo-player-time-tracking-using-script).

Save this timestamp in the `local storage` or `session-storage` every now and then.
When to save it is up to you, `ngOnDestroy()` is a possibility but keep in mind it isn't called if the browser is closed unexpectedly (but you can use a workaround: [Angular 2 - Execute code when closing window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38999842/angular-2-execute-code-when-closing-window)), or you could define an interval.

Being in the local storage you don't have to worry about your component being destroyed and re-instantiated, the value is always there.

Then every time you instantiate the component with the video, check if the local storage value is set to something (`localStorage.getValue('timestamp')`) if so assign your component var to it (maybe in `ngOnInit()`), and add `?autoplay=1#t={timestamp}` to your vimeo iframe url if there's a `timestamp` var in your component exists.

On top of all that you'll probably to clear the `local storage` value at some point (video finished,...) and there might be some other things to tweak but that's my idea anyway.

---

This is not a solution but more like some rough directions to solve your problem.
I haven't tested any of it but I hope it gets you somewhat started. Feel free to comment on what I might have missed.